# How do I animate a UIView along a circular path inside CustomInfoWindow of marker of Googlemap

Tags: ios, animation, google-maps-markers

I am developing an TaxiApp on IOS in which i am using GoogleMaps.
I want to show a circular animation inside `CustomInfoWindow` on `GMSMarker`.

As `CustomInfoWindow` shows only a static circular path without animation my question is:
How do I animate a UIView along a circular path inside `CustomInfoWindow`?

Comment: You need a custom GMSMarker with an animation inside is what you need?